# Mollifiers: Nonexample?

Tags: calculus, integration, functional-analysis, distribution-theory

A smooth, compactly supported, normalized, positive, etc. function is called mollifier if:
$$\varphi_\varepsilon(x):=\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\varphi\left(\frac{x}{\varepsilon}\right):\quad\varphi_\varepsilon(x)\to\delta(x)$$
*(See wikipedia: [Mollifiers: Definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier#Definition) )*

Now I'm just wondering wether this requirement can fail in general:
$$\varphi\in\mathcal{C}_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}):\quad\varphi_\varepsilon(x)\nrightarrow\delta(x)\quad\left(\int\varphi(x)dx=1\right)$$
*(I guess so but what would be an appropriate example?)*

Comment: It is in no extend normable.

Comment: @daw: It cannot satisfy normalization: $\int\varphi(x)dx=1$

Comment: But it still does the job as it weights closer and closer to zero, doesn't it? I mean at least for continuous functions it will definitely work...

Comment: The condition is redundant. If $\varphi \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with $\int\varphi\,dx = 1$, then $\varphi_\varepsilon(x) = \frac{1}{\varepsilon^n}\varphi(x/\varepsilon)$ satisfies $$\lim_{\varepsilon \searrow 0} \varphi_{\varepsilon} = \delta$$ in $\mathscr{D}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Comment: Thanks! I thought so already hehe ;) ....but what's the argument?

Comment: Write down the integral $\int \varphi_\varepsilon(x)\cdot\psi(x)\,dx$ for a $\psi\in\mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, change variables $x = \varepsilon y$, estimate.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Ah yep right for compactly supported mollifiers and continuous test functions that is really not as hard. Besides does it still hold for mollifier say smooth but not necessarily compactly supported?

Comment: Not much of a difference. You split the integral in one part $\lvert y\rvert > R$ where $\int_{\lvert y\rvert > R} \lvert \varphi(y)\rvert\,dy < \delta$, and the part $\lvert y\rvert \leqslant R$. For the $\lvert y\rvert > R$ part, you have the estimate $2\lVert\psi\rVert_\infty \delta$, and for the other part, $\lVert\varphi\rVert_1\cdot \sup \{\lvert \psi(z) - \psi(0)\rvert : \lvert z\rvert \leqslant \varepsilon\cdot R\}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: But a smooth test function if merely continuous but not compactly supported neither then it may be unbounded...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The condition is redundant. In fact, we have the stronger

**Proposition:** Let $\varphi \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \varphi(x)\,dx = 1$. For $\varepsilon > 0$ define $\varphi_\varepsilon \colon x \mapsto \varepsilon^{-n}\cdot \varphi(x/\varepsilon)$. Then

$$\lim_{\varepsilon \searrow 0} \varphi_\varepsilon = \delta$$

in the sense of distributions.

**Proof:** Let $\psi \in \mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Then

\begin{align}
\left\lvert \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\varphi_{\varepsilon}(x)\psi(x)\,dx - \psi(0)\right\rvert
&= \left\lvert \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \varphi(y)\psi(\varepsilon y)\,dy - \psi(0)\right\rvert\\
&= \left\lvert \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\varphi(y)\bigl(\psi(\varepsilon y) - \psi(0)\bigr)\,dy\right\rvert\\
&\leqslant \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \lvert \varphi(y)\rvert\cdot \lvert \psi(\varepsilon y) - \psi(0)\rvert\,dy\\
&= \int_{\lvert y\rvert \leqslant R} \lvert \varphi(y)\rvert\cdot \lvert \psi(\varepsilon y) - \psi(0)\rvert\,dy + \int_{\lvert y\rvert > R} \lvert \varphi(y)\rvert\cdot \lvert \psi(\varepsilon y) - \psi(0)\rvert\,dy\\
&\leqslant \sup_{\lvert z\rvert \leqslant \varepsilon R} \lvert \psi(z) - \psi(0)\rvert \int_{\lvert y\rvert \leqslant R} \lvert\varphi(y)\rvert\,dy + 2\max_{z\in \mathbb{R}^n} \lvert\psi(z)\rvert \int_{\lvert y\rvert > R} \lvert\varphi(y)\rvert\,dy\\
&\leqslant \lVert\varphi\rVert_{L^1} \cdot \lVert\psi\rVert_{H^{1,\infty}}\cdot R\cdot \varepsilon + 2\lVert \psi\rVert_{L^\infty} \underbrace{\int_{\lvert y\rvert > R} \lvert\varphi(y)\rvert\,dy}_{A(R)}.
\end{align}

Since $\varphi \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, we have $A(R) \to 0$ as $R\to \infty$, and thus, for any given $\eta > 0$, we can choose $R\in (0,\infty)$ such that

$$2\lVert \psi\rVert_{L^\infty} \cdot A(R) < \frac{\eta}{2}.$$

Then we can set

$$\varepsilon_0 := \frac{\eta}{1 + 2\lVert\varphi\rVert_{L^1}\lVert\psi\rVert_{H^{1,\infty}}R}$$

and have

$$\left\lvert \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \varphi_\varepsilon(x)\psi(x)\,dx - \psi(0) \right\rvert < \eta$$

for all $\varepsilon \leqslant \varepsilon_0$. The choices of $R$ and $\varepsilon_0$ can be made uniformly on bounded subsets of $\mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (just replace the $\lVert\psi\rVert_{X}$ expressions by positive constants), hence we have

$$\varphi_\varepsilon \to \delta$$

in the sense of distributions.

Comment: Is the bounded subset $\mathbb{D}$ meant to be bounded subset of $\mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Comment: Yes, of course, thanks. Muscle memory typed the wrong LaTeX :(

Comment: That's a nice merge btw: R became D and \mathscr became \mathbb ^^